# Autolayout iOS with single uiviewcontroller and multiple view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am working on an app that is using a few UIViewcontrollers with multiple UIViews. I am trying to setup autolayout but the UIViews are not scaling to the UIViewcontroller size. Can someone point me to a way to resolve this with out the need to redesign the app architecture?

---

So I have a UIViewController and a subview UIView (addNoteUIView)

When I am adding the subview to the viewController the 
subview Addnote View not resizing via auto layout to the bounds of the screen and it get cropped.

[the subview does not resize to the bounds of the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwDlG.png)

How to you fix the second UIView (add note view) to follow the bounds of the device?

**EDIT**

Thanks Vishal

I am setting the frame on viewdidload

```
[self.collectionView setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.collectionView setNeedsLayout];
```

But, I am getting this behavior from the cells. Why is this happening? multiple bounds? 
[see image with collection view cell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0tR.png)

my code for the collection item size

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CGRect screenRect = [_collectionView bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    CGFloat cellWidth = (screenWidth / (_lcolumns)); //Replace the divisor with the column count requirement. Make sure to have it in float.
    CGFloat cellHeight = (screenHeight / (_lrows));

    if(cellWidth < cellHeight)
        return  CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
    else
        return  CGSizeMake(cellHeight, cellHeight);

}
```

Comment: its not clear what you want to achieve. show us some working code or layout.

Comment: show us a screenshot of your problem. It's hard to understand what's the problem as a whole

Comment: I updated the question above - hope that makes it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Its not resize using autolayout you need to set frame OR you need to give constraints programatically.